# What to do if you find the answer to your own question?

Tags: support, self-answer

For the second time (IIRC) since I have joined SO, I have found the answer on my own, immediately (within minutes) after posting the question. I answered my own question the first time, but seeing that there are some "scandals" where people ask and answer, just to get reputation, I am not so sure anymore. Sure I can select my own answer after 2 days, but I am confused.

Comment: If you're finding your own answers within minutes after posting... wait a few more minutes before posting the next one. :)

Comment: Waiting doesn't help anyone.  In fact I would think that an immediate ask and answer would be a good thing.  If something stumped you for a bit, why not share the answer with the community?

Comment: I'm kind of relieved to see this question. One of my first questions was about something I later figured out the answer for (maybe a day later, after a lot more digging) and I just answered it without thinking - I figured that if someone else came with the same question, they'd want to see the information / answer even if it was found by the same person. *whew*

Comment: @theTuxRacer: I was kind of expecting you to answer this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but seeing that there are some "scandals" where people ask and answer, just to get get reputation, I am not so sure anymore.

No, this is perfectly okay practice. There is no rep gain for answering your own question; accepting your own answer will not give you the 15-point bonus; and you can't upvote your own answer.

If no other answer is correct, it is perfectly fine to go this way; it is even [encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking).

Comment: oh right, the scandal was creating a duplicate account, and upvoting. Thanks.