# If I self-delete fast enough, do I still receive the automatic downvote?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if you find the answer to your own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68507/what-to-do-if-you-find-the-answer-to-your-own-question)

I found the answer with Google not long after posting my question. Do I still get the automatic downvote punishment if the question is self-deleted fast enough?

Comment: What "automatic downvote punishment"?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I assume it's the down-vote you get when a question is closed as Off Topic or Not a Real Question.

Comment: I heard this also happens if you delete your own question

Comment: @ChrisF I didn't know that closing a question results in a down-vote of any kind. Is this covered in a part of the FAQ I haven't read?

Comment: Why not answer your own question instead?

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr - there's no down-vote penalty if you delete your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting your own questions *can* contribute toward a question ban, I believe, though the algorithm isn't exactly public and I'm not sure a deleted question with no activity counts any less than a deleted question that has been down-voted and VtC'd.

If you've found the answer, I'd agree with S.L. Barth - you're much better off posting an answer to the question (and not just a link to the answer you found on Google).

In the long run, this is better off for other readers (who may come across the same problem), better for the site (by providing another quality answer), better off for you (since you may attract better answers), and better for other contributors (who may be able to provide a better answer). As such I would post the answer (to avoid others duplicating work) but I wouldn't self-accept immediately - give other folks a chance to absorb your challenge and propose an alternate solution.

This assumes the question wasn't a brain-dead one that can only have one answer, like "what is the function name for x?"

Comment: good advice thanks my question was about autoit and the answer was on their forums